# Apple sandbox server down

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Am i the only one who is facing this problem with the Apple sandbox server being down when trying to do in app purchases

I keep getting an error saying " Cant connect to Itunes store

We have a consumable IAP product that is currently in "Ready to Submit" phase in the app store. When we to start purchasing the product in sandbox environment by adding SKPayment to SKPaymentQueue, we get an error that says "Cannot connect to App Store". This takes a few minutes and is not instantaneous. Also attempted to buy a subscription IAP in the sandbox environment and that failed too.

Comment: Snadbox testing shows some errors sometimes. Checkout few threads. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87791

Comment: Related but since last 2 weeks no matter what I do, it just continuously fails

Comment: I'm also having sandbox issue in Australia.